# Dúvida exercício com listas

Tags: python, lista

Segue o problema:

Crie uma função em Python que recebe uma lista e retorna quantos números são positivos. Caso um elemento da lista não seja um número inteiro ou real (float), a função deve parar e retornar um erro informando que a lista só pode ter elementos com valores numéricos.

Eu consegui fazer um código, mas ele sempre roda até o final, a intenção é que se a entrada da lista for uma string o código deveria parar e retornar somente a mensagem de erro.

Segue o código que eu escrevi:

```
lista = input('Digite uma lista de numeros')  
def maior_que_zero(x):  
    if not type(x)is float and not type (x) is int:  
        print('Erro digite somente numeros')  
    elif (x) > 0:  
        return True  
    elif (x) < 0:   
        return False  
lista_valida = filter(maior_que_zero, lista)  
print 'Numeros positivos' + ' '+ str(len (lista_valida))
```

Comment: Sua `lista` será sempre uma string, pois o retorno da função `input` é desse tipo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a alguma forma de mudar isso?

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro, vamos criar uma função chamada `main`, que será o ponto de entrada do seu programa, e colocar uma `if` assegurando que a função só será chamada quando o script for executado diretamente.

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Beleza, agora podemos retirar aquele `pass` e então escrever o programa propriamente dito. O código que eu mostrarei a partir daqui deve ser colocado dentro da função `main`.

De início, vamos inicializar o contador de números positivos.

```
contagem_positivos = 0
```

Depois, vamos pedir ao usuário pra digitar a entrada.

```
entrada = input('Digite uma lista de numeros, separada por espaços: ')
```

A linha é uma string, não uma lista. É preciso chamar o método `.split` para quebrar a string nos espaços em branco e tranformá-la em uma lista de strings.

```
lista = entrada.split()
```

Ou seja, se o usuário informou `1 0 -3 2`, o retorno do `.split` será `['1', '0', '-3', '2']` (note que essa é uma lista de strings, não de números!)

Feito isso, vamos iterar por cada elemento da lista.

```
for elemento in lista:
```

Dentro do laço, tentamos converter cada elemento para um número. Se a conversão não der certo, printamos o erro e encerramos o programa.

```
    try:
        numero = float(elemento)
    except ValueError:
        print('Erro: Somente números')
        return
```

Se a conversão der certo, verificamos se o número é positivo e, se for, incrementamos o contador.

```
    if numero > 0:
        contagem_positivos += 1
```

Pronto. Depois do loop, basta exibir o conteúdo do contador.

```
print('Quantidade de números positivos:', contagem_positivos)
```

Segue o código completo.

```
def main():
    contagem_positivos = 0

    entrada = input('Digite uma lista de numeros, separada por espaços: ')

    lista = entrada.split()

    for elemento in lista:
        try:
            numero = float(elemento)
        except ValueError:
            print('Erro: Somente números')
            return

        if numero > 0:
            contagem_positivos += 1

    print('Quantidade de números positivos:', contagem_positivos)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Leitura adicional:

- https://blog.alura.com.br/o-que-significa-if-name-main-no-python/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 3):

Embora as duas outras respostas sigam o mesmo raciocínio do código mostrado na pergunta e contenham algoritmos para contar números positivos em uma lista, nenhuma delas atende ao enunciado da questão.

Vejamos, por partes:

> *Crie uma função em Python que recebe uma lista*

O objetivo da questão é criar uma função que tem um parâmetro: uma lista.

O texto não pede para receber dados do usuário ou para fazer a crítica se o valor é numérico antes de chamar essa função, muito menos receber dados **dentro** da função.

E continua:

> *e retorna quantos números são positivos*

Mais uma vez, a questão não pede para que a função imprima quantos números são positivos. Tudo o que ela precisa fazer é **retornar** a contagem de números positivos.

Por fim:

> Caso um elemento da lista não seja um número inteiro ou real (float), a função deve parar e retornar um erro informando que a lista só pode ter elementos com valores numéricos.

Nesse caso, não fica claro se o "erro" é um objeto do tipo `Error` ou uma String, mas considerando que o código que vai chamar a função sabe que ela pode retornar um erro, é mais conveniente usar o princípio do encapsulamento e retornar um objeto do tipo `Error`. Além disso, qualquer refactoring da função para incluir mais informações no retorno de erro seria transparente para todas as linhas que chamam essa função.

**Por que isso é importante?**

Se essa função for chamada a partir de um teste unitário, nenhuma das outras respostas vai funcionar.

Mas não é só por isso...

Existe um ditado que diz: *"O computador não faz o que você quer, ele faz o que você manda!"*

Da mesma forma, o programador precisa entender o problema e ser capaz de seguir as instruções fornecidas.

O "*gold plating*", ou "dourar a pílula" em bom português, é uma das causas do fracasso de muitos projetos de software.

Como última consideração, sugiro a simplicidade, citando o Zen Of Python:

> *Simple is better than complex.*
>
> *Readability counts.*

Com base em tudo isso, a minha resposta é essa:

```
def positivos(lista):
    try:
        positivos = [float(i) for i in lista if i > 0]
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('A lista só pode ter elementos com valores numéricos.')
    return len(positivos)
```

Essa resposta usa uma compreensão de lista para reduzir a lista original a uma outra somente com os números positivos.

A função `float(i)` garante que o número é inteiro ou real, ou gera um TypeError;

Para cada valor da lista `for i in lista`;

Se o valor for positivo `if i > 0`.

O retorno é o tamanho da lista de números positivos, ou seja, a quantidade.
`return len(positivos)`

Algumas entradas de teste:

```
print(positivos([-1, 0, 1]))
print(positivos([-1, 0]))
print(positivos([-1, 0, 'a']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas corretas para resolver esta questão é utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
def quantidade_positivos(numeros):
    cont = 0
    for x in numeros:  
        if x > 0:
            cont += 1  

    print(f'\033[32mA quantidade de números positivos é: {cont}\033[m')


while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Desejas inserir quantos valores? '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

todos_numeros = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    while True:
        try:
            v = float(input(f'Digite o {c}º valor: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números reais!\033[m')
    todos_numeros.append(v)

quantidade_positivos(todos_numeros)
```

Observe que quando executamos este algoritmo recebemos a mensagem `Desejas inserir quantos valores?`. Neste momento devemos digitar um número `inteiro` representando a quantidade de valores que iremos inserir na lista.

Depois disso recebemos a mensagem `Digite o 1º valor:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o primeiro valor. Em seguida, devemos digitar os demais valores.

**OBSERVAÇÃO 1**

Durante a inserção dos valores, o bloco `try except` verifica se os valores digitados são de fato números reais. Caso positivo, o valor será adicionado na lista `todos_numeros`. Caso contrário, receberemos a mensagem `Valor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números reais!`.

Depois de termos inserido, corretamente todos os valores, a lista será enviada para a função `quantidade_positivos`. Chegando nesta função, a lista será percorrida pelo `for` e todos os valores positivos serão contados, acumulando sua contagem na variável `cont`.

Posteriormente, a função `quantidade_positivos` exibe a quantidade de números positivos existente na lista.

**OBSERVAÇÃO 2**

Para representarmos o número 2 como positivo basta digitarmos **2**, ao passo que para representarmos o número 2 como negativo basta digitarmos **-2**.